Examples of $\mathcal{L}^1_{\text{loc}}$ fuctions which are differentiable only in the distribution sense
From what I've read in Rudin's Functional Analysis, distributions generalize functions in the sense that any $\mathcal{L}^1_{\text{loc}}$ function "is" a distribution by
$$\Lambda_f : \mathcal{D}\to\mathbb{C}:\phi\mapsto\int\phi f.$$
Later in the chapter he defines differentiation on distributions by
$$(D^\alpha\Lambda)(\phi) = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\Lambda(D^\alpha\phi)$$
This all seems to points to the existence of functions which are not differentiable in the ordinary sense, but are differentiable in the distribution sense. In particular, are non-differentiable $\mathcal{L}^1_{\text{loc}}$ functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ which have a derivative $g:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ in the distribution sense? If so, what do $f$ and $g$ look like?

One simple example is $f(x)=|x|$.  Obviously, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.  But clearly we have for $\phi\in C_C^\infty$
$$\begin{align}
\langle f',\phi\rangle&=-\langle f,\phi'\rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 x\phi'(x)\,dx-\int_0^\infty x\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x)\phi(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside distribution.
Therefore, in distribution we find that
$$(|x|)'=H(x)$$

Of course, another simple example is the Heaviside function.  Note that
$$\begin{align}
\langle H',\phi\rangle &=-\langle H,\phi'\rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 \phi'(x)\,dx-\int_0^\infty \phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=2\phi(0)
\end{align}$$
And hence, we find that in distribution
$$H'(x)=2\delta(x)$$

Of course, a third example is $f(x)=\log(|x|)$.  Clearly, $f$ has an unbounded derivative at $x=0$.  However,
$$\begin{align}
\langle f',\phi\rangle&=-\langle f,\phi'\rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(|x|)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge \varepsilon}\log(|x|)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \log(-x)\phi'(x)\,dx-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^\infty \log(x)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge \varepsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx
\end{align}$$
where $\text{PV}$ denotes a Principal Value.  Hence, we find that in distribution
$$\left(\log(|x|)\right)'=\text{PV}\left(\frac1x\right)$$
